# Mail PEAR package not sending email

Tags: php, mysql, email, smtp

I've got a script set up which is supposed to email based on a query. The code is like this:

```
$firemail = mysql_query("SELECT `email` from `users` WHERE `reference` = ''$customer' ");
$to      = $firemail;
```

Ignoring the fact that this isn't PDO I then pass $firemail to smtp as follows:

```
$headers = array (
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $firemail,
    'Subject' => $subject,
    'Reply-To' => 'test@test.com',
    'MIME-Version' => "1.0",
    'Content-type' => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n");
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'smtp.myservice.com',
        'port' => '123',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'user@test.com',
        'password' => 'supersecretpassword'
    ));
```

I've tested that the SMTP works, it sends the email as designed when I manually type in the recipient. The query that $firemail contains is valid, and returns the expected result. I've echoed out the $customer var and this returns the expected result.

So assuming that all of my code is valid and operating as it should be. Why am I not receiving the email?

Thanks!

Comment: you are not geeting any result...instead, you are storing a mysql object in you `$firemail` var ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I took a quick look through the list and error_reporting(-1) returns no errors. I'm mailing through PHPMailer and am not suppressing any error messages using @. The address definitely works when I hard-code it in, and I'm emailing through Mandrill (which doesn't receive the message, suggesting the issue is on my side) so spam-blocking isn't a problem. I added a condition to catch errors and its returning saying the message was sent.

Comment: @RobertRozas - I am an idiot! Thanks for that, fixed it. More coffee needed!

Comment: @RobertRozas Post that as an answer so we can upvote you and the question-asker can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Okidokis...writing xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is returning a mysql object instead a result:

```
$firemail = mysql_query("SELECT `email` from `users` WHERE `reference` = ''$customer' ");
$to = $firemail;
```

Should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `email` from `users` WHERE `reference` = ''$customer'");

while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $firemail[] = $fila['email']
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Me being dumb ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnConde ...happy new year :)